# Java -- Patterns -- Matcher.group()?

Tags: java, design-patterns, matcher

So I have a document, and a specified n-gram target string. I'm trying to find the indexes of all occurrences of the target string.

```
final Pattern WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher matcher = WORD_PATTERN.matcher("the lazy dog, jumps, the lazy dog.");
```

So the string is "the lazy dog, jumps, the lazy dog."

Say my target n-gram is "the lazy". I essentially 'iterate' through the entire string as follows, adding 'n' words to a linked list, currentNGram. If all of the words in currentNGram match the target n-gram, I save the index. Else, I remove the first element of the linked list, and append on the next word in the input string (eg. check the next successive n-gram in the document).

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    while (currentNGram.size() < lengthOfTargetNTuple) { 
        currentNGram.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(currentNGram.getLast());
    }
}
```

So that's all fine and dandy, but my next problem is that I have to 'iterate' through the document again, and find the distance of every n-gram to the nearest target n-gram. So I take the exact same approach. Except this time, when I reinitialize the matcher, and run the loop as follows,

```
 while (matcher.find()) {
        while (currentGram.size() < lengthOfTargetNTuple) {
            currentGram.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());
                    System.out.println(currentGram.printLast()) // Psuedocode
        }
```

it prints the word "the" 7 times instead of printing "the" "lazy" "dog" "jumps", etc. However,

```
while (matcher.find()) {
        while (currentGram.size() < lengthOfTargetNTuple) {
            currentGram.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());
        }
        System.out.println(matcher.group()); // Prints words in order, correctly
}
```

Why is this? How come the matcher.group() method call printed out words in their correct order in the first problem, but not the second? Any direction would be greatly appreciated; I know this was a long post, sorry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, some basic knowledge. Let's see what [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) does...

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>   This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

Next, let's take a peek at [`Matcher.group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29)

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

---

Now that we understand how they work, let's see what the following loop does.

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    while (currentGram.size() < lengthOfTargetNTuple) {
        currentGram.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());
                System.out.println(currentGram.printLast()) // Psuedocode
    }
}
```

You're printing `currentGram.printLast` several times per `matcher.find` call -- to be precise, `lengthOfTargetNTuple` times. `currentGram.printLast` must be resulting in that which was just added -- `matcher.group().toLowerCase()`. Since we've only called `matcher.find` once for this entire loop, this value is not going to change.

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    while (currentGram.size() < lengthOfTargetNTuple) {
        currentGram.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());
    }
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // Prints words in order, correctly
}
```

Here, however, you are printing `matcher.group` only once per `match.find` invoke. This means you only print each matched subsequence *once*, rather than `lengthOfTargetNTuple` times.